# Error when trying to test a React components library using yarn link

Tags: reactjs, typescript, yarnpkg

I am working on a React components library that was created using create-react-app. In my main project directory, /my-components-lib, I did

```
yarn link
```

Then I created a test app that would consume this library. I also created it using create-react-app. In /my-test-app, I did

```
yarn link my-components-library
```

And then in /my-test-app/App.js, I imported the component like this:

```
import Button from "my-components-library/src/components/button"
```

However, I got these errors

```
ERROR in ../my-components-library/src/components/button= 15:7
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (15:7)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
 * ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| import { compose } from 'src/utils/fp'
| 
> export interface ButtonProps extends Omit<MuiButtonProps, 'variant' | 'color' | 'background'> {
|   variant?: 'primary' | 'secondary' | 'tertiary' | 'cta'
|   size?: 'small' | 'medium' | 'large'

webpack compiled with 1 error

ERROR in node_modules/my-components-library/src/components/Button.tsx:1:30
TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/utils/colorHelpers' or its corresponding type declarations.
  > 1 | import { hexToRgbaCss } from 'src/utils/colorHelpers'
      |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    2 | import { Components } from './themes/model'
    3 |
    4 | export const generateColors = (colors): Components => {
```

How do I fix this? I just want to test my package locally before publishing it

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues. The first error is because by default Webpack won't load the typescript loader for modules in `node_modules`. Normally, that's because dependencies have their own build step and the TS is already compiled down. If you just want to use the source though for dev purposes you would need to [change the config of `ts-loader` to compile this.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-loader#allowtsinnodemodules)

The second problem seems to me like your import is missing a `./`. You probably meant `../utils/colorHelpers` or whatever the *relative* path is in your case. If this works when developing the package in isolation, that'll be because `create-react-app` adds web pack aliases to support that kind of imports from the package root. But again, your parent project is using its *own* Webpack compilation process.

So, things get more complicated now because `create-react-app` doesn't let you edit the Webpack config. You could use something like [craco](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@craco/craco).

Its a lot of effort, so it might be better to actually do a `build` of your dependent component library and then in your parent project, you would be importing the built version, and not from source. Importing from source gives you all the problems you are seeing where you end up bringing the build config of the dependent project into your parent.

[You might consider monorepos like Yarn workspaces.](https://medium.com/@tungdang/cra-and-yarn-workspace-cbb466aecd7a) where both modules are in the same project and everything is built from source from the same build process. Probably this is your best option if you don't intend to publish your component library by itself as its own project -- but it sounds like you do, so that's probably out as an option.

If you really want to test as a real consumer would, you need to build your component library and publish the built version and not the source, and reference the built version in the component libraries `package.json`'s `main` or `module`. That means anyone using your package (including via `link:`) will be decoupled from its build process.

Comment: I did build the library first and then referenced it in package.json

Comment: Can you share the package.json in the original post of the component library?

Comment: Do you know how I can import the built version? I have built it using rollup and now have a build folder that contains index.js, index.esm.js, index.js.map, and index.esm.js.map. How do I import this built version in the consumer app and how would the consumer app use it?

Comment: Firstly, in the core package, change `package.json` so that `module` points to the `index.esm.js` in the build folder. You can now link it as you did before, and the problem should be solved.